# Dash Plotly Dashboard select files from dropdown and display data

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Dashboard which is working with the data from two csv (csv 1, csv2) files from two folders, they are running through a lot of pre-processing stuff and in the end they display graphs, tables and so on. The dashboard is running fine, each csv file is responsible for its own graphs, so they don't overlap each other.

I get new files every week, so I thought about a dashboard which is running with dummy graphs at the start and two drop down menus. One is containing automaticly all files which are in the csv1 folder, the other one should show all files from csv2 folder. By clicking one csv file the graphs should update the dashboard and showing the new data.

Is this possible with dash and plotly?